# Is it possible to overload the native HTMLInputElement value getter?

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering if it is possible to modify a `HTMLInputElement` to display something different than the value prop returns.

Why that? Well sometimes you want to display the user something nice like a **string**, but you want to post an **ID** to the server. If you are using multiple logic/plugins on the input it starts getting problematic with using an additional fake one. So why not include both into one?! =)

I already noticed it is possible to define a getter for the `value` prop. But I loose the native setter functionality which will change the displayed text. =/

HTML:

```
<input id="foobar" type="text"/>
```

JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById('foobar');
    input.value = 'Mr. Foo Bar';
    input.myHiddenValue = 123;

Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', {
    get: function(){
        return this.myHiddenValue; 
    }
});
```

So if you can tell me, if this is possible and keep the native setter or just a silly late night idea, let me know xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I don't recommend doing that, you can get (and cache) the native setter by using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, e.g:

```js
(function() {
  var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');

  descriptor.get = function() {
    // do whatever you want to do here
  }

  Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value', descriptor);  
})();
```

Comment: Wow, this really works via prototype. =D
Too bad the display value is not transferred via post - damn!

Comment: you forgot the quotes for ``value`` in ``defineProperty()``

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a dropdown menu? It's a better UI for the user, and does everything you want:

```html
<div ng-app>
  <select ng-model="test">
    <!-- Angular used to show selection, but not needed -->
    <option value="0">Coffee</option>
    <option value="1">Breakfast</option>
    <option value="2">Morning Snack</option>
    <option value="3">Lunch</option>
    <option value="4">Afternoon Snack</option>
    <option value="5">Dinner</option>
    <option value="6">Dessert</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  Selection: {{test}}
</div>

<!-- Angular used to show selection. Input.value will work the same way -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

If you want something more of a input/dropdown hybrid (like your comment), you can try the [Selectize.js library](https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").selectize();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/css/selectize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/master/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>

<select id="test" placeholder="Select a meal...">
  <option value="0">Coffee</option>
  <option value="1">Breakfast</option>
  <option value="2">Morning Snack</option>
  <option value="3">Lunch</option>
  <option value="4">Afternoon Snack</option>
  <option value="5">Dinner</option>
  <option value="6">Dessert</option>
</select>
```

Selectize.js also supports ajax option loading, and searching. I really love it.

Comment: In general yes, but in my case I got more than 50K options. The input uses some google-like auto completer. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @Möhre You can try selectize js (look at my answer for an example)